# How to authenticate user after redirect from google?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs, passport.js, google-authentication

I'm implementing google OAuth2 with passport.js, nest.js and React.

In my React app it will redirect the user to this endpoint `http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google`

```
// React 
<button label="login" onClick={window.location.href('http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google')}/>


// Nest.js endpoint
  @Get('google')
  @UseGuards(GoogleOAuthGuard)
  async googleAuth() {}
```

Once the user authenicates, google redirect's the user to another endpoint (`http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google/redirect`) in my Nest.js API. Note: I have set this up as the redirect url in google developer console.

```
// get's the user data from the redirect, create tokens, saves in the DB etc...
  @Get('google/redirect')
  @UseGuards(GoogleOAuthGuard)
  async googleAuthRedirect(@Req() req: Request): Promise<User & Tokens> {
    const user = <UserType>req.user;

    return this.authService.googleAuth(user);
  }

// My passport.js google strategy setup
export class GoogleOAuthStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      clientID: configService.get<string>('OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
      clientSecret: configService.get<string>('OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      callbackURL: configService.get<string>('OAUTH_GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL'),
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }
```

My question is what happens afterwards? How will my React app get access to the object that is returned from `http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google/redirect`? (NOTE: this is an api endpoint, not a React path). Should my React app call `http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google/redirect`?

I land here after redirect:
[image]

port 3000 is my api route, my React app is on port 3001. How would I get the data into my React app?

Answer (score -1):

After you do login via google auth, via this Endpoint 'http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google', your server application will automatically redirect to this endpoint http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google/redirect, and after that you will get any information from google oauth such as profile user, access token, and refresh token (which was returned by redirect endpoint). so you don't need to call http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/auth/google/redirect on your react app

Comment: So after it lands on my redirect page, which is "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect", this is port 3000. My react app is on port 3001. So how do I get the data to my React app on port 3001?

Comment: I added a screenshot after the redirect, hope this will explain my question better

Comment: Maybe after you got the response, you can try redirecting your react app on port 3001 on dashboard page or home page, and save the OAuth's response on your local storage for authorization.

Comment: I figured out that Nestjs has a @Redirect() decorator, so I can return a redirect Url with hash params (i.e. email, userName etc...) to the FE. And the FE can grab those hash params and authenticate the user

Comment: i haven't tried to use redirect on my API or server application, maybe you can check via the documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#redirection

Comment: I didn't know there was a redirect I could've used, this solution is working, thanks.